# Does "playhill" make sense as an english word?

Tags: names, titles, brands

I'd like to use the word "playhill" for a gaming website address like playhill.net - does this word combination work in native english? Or does it sound very odd?

Comment: It works, but it sounds odd, or at least as odd as any contrived URL can sound. To me, the word combination does not invoke any accurate feelings about the actual site usage, instead it suggests some kind of kids playground or fun activity location.

Comment: There are very, very few [english words](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/english). And no, *playhill* is most definitely not one of them.

Comment: That being said, this kind of questions is off-topic here. It is a name. It can be anything at all. You can name it playhill, plyhl, playhagalkj, хабаровск, or Susan. And they will all mean the exact same thing.

Comment: Looks like a typo for 'playbill'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think *play* is the odd word here. Play is not frequently used as a noun in English, unless one is referring to the type of play that is performed on a stage.